# I have a 1TB external hard disk from Toshiba, which show up on Windows but can't format it and on Ubuntu it doesn't even show up

Tags: hard-drive

This is Toshiba MK1059GSM external Hard Drive.It will show up on Windows and says you need format it before you use it and click on Format but it doesn't get formatted and shows an error saying Format failed it works sometimes on windows and ubuntu.Now at the present on Ubuntu it doesn't even show up . I hope you guys understand what's the issue.Please help me
output of sudo lsusb:
sudo lsusb
[sudo] password for jaganjose2009:
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 0480:a004 Toshiba America Inc
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF9055 Toshiba Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5138 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
output of sudo lsblk:
sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop2    7:2    0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop3    7:3    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop4    7:4    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2344
loop5    7:5    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop6    7:6    0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1405
loop7    7:7    0 248.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop8    7:8    0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop9    7:9    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop10   7:10   0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop11   7:11   0 169.6M  1 loop /snap/spotify/58
loop12   7:12   0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop13   7:13   0  43.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15177
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdc2   8:34   0     1K  0 part
└─sdc5   8:37   0 232.4G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom

After sometime its showing like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX8Oe.png)

Comment: Where is it not showing up? Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lsblk`?

Comment: Do you have an external power supply for the disk?  It just may need more power than one USB port can supply, and the "Y" USB cables sometimes work, but depends upon the internal wiring the two USBs on different buses.

Comment: lsblk does not need sudo for a basic check

Comment: @ubfan1 it does not have external power supply.Just one cable